# Unable to insert to remote database C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio-2012

I've been attempting to write to a remote database, however I keep receiving errors when I attempt `INSERT INTO`. I can read from the database just fine and have used to to make sure my connection is working.

NOTE: I am using the MySQL extension.

Here is a part of my function:

```
try
                {
                    query = "INSTERT INTO users (user_name, password, admin) VALUES ('" + username + "', '" + password + "', '0')";
                    command = new MySqlCommand(query, databaseConnection.getConnection());
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    query = "INSERT INTO players (user_id, first_name, last_name, phone, email, japanese_schoolgirl, status) VALUES('" + username + "','" + firstName + "','" + lastName + "','" + phoneNumber + "','" + emailAddress + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(japaneseSchoolgirl) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(status) + "')";
                    command = new MySqlCommand(query, databaseConnection.getConnection());
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string error = "SQL query failed to add user to database \n" + ex;
                    MessageBox.Show(error, "Username Taken", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
```

I receive the following error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): you have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to  your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO
>   users(user_name, password, admin) VALUES ('Username1', 'pass1', ''0'
>   at line 1

As you can imagine, I'v already looked at the manual and cannot find anything wrong with my SQL syntax. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

"INSTERT" - That's what you have mispelled in your query.